# spring integration jsonToObjecttransformer exception

Tags: java, json, spring-integration

I ma using spring integration to get data from Mongo DB and then invoke a Transformer.
I read about `JsonToObjectTransformer` which can be used to convert a json to a corresponding object.
I am trying to achieve the same but I get an exception.

```
    'json' argument must be an instance of: 
[class java.lang.String, 
class [B, class java.io.File, 
class java.net.URL, 
class java.io.InputStream, 
class java.io.Reader] , 
but gotten: class java.util.ArrayList
```

The issue is that when I poll from the MongoDB, I get the payload in the following form:-

```
[
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5ab3e2af453d578d2e07090b"} , "status" : "new" , "message" : "a|b|c|d"}, 
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5ab3ea28453d578d2e07090d"} , "status" : "new" , "message" : "a|b|c|d|e"}
]
```

This pay load gets passed to the Transformer that uses a `JsonToObjectTransfomer`.

Since the json is a list and starts with a `[` , I get an exception while converting to an object.

One possible solution is to use an enricher to enrich the payload before being passed to the transformer.

But are there any other solution to this?

Thanks,

Amar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve it by doing the following:-

public MessageSource mongoMessageSource(MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory) {

```
    MongoDbMessageSource mongoDbMessageSource = new MongoDbMessageSource(mongoDbFactory,
            new LiteralExpression(new BasicDBObject("status","new").toString().concat(".limit(1)")));
    mongoDbMessageSource.
            setCollectionNameExpression(new LiteralExpression("BankAccountDetail"));
    mongoDbMessageSource.setEntityClass(AccountBalanceDetailsWrapper.class);//added this for default
    return mongoDbMessageSource;
```

Then in the Transformer

```
public void show(Message<List<AccountBalanceDetailsWrapper>> message) {
        message.getPayload().stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the point is that `java.util.ArrayList` is not a JSON any more. It is really and `Object`. So, transformer is right: you don't give it an expected type for parsing and transformation.

Not sure how you get a result from MongoDB, but it is already `java.util.ArrayList` - the driver or Spring Data has done the trick for you already and you have converted JSON to list of POJOs or Maps.

Answer (score 0):

> but gotten: class java.util.ArrayList

Sounds like it's already been deserialized from JSON.